# trace wordpress functions and including files

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to learn how Worpress is working internally. I have to find out how the data is flowing around functions and files. Is there any tool available for windows to find out this ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function [debug_backtrace()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) in PHP and setup [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/install). Both will show you all the functions called and the files they're in.

Answer (score 0):

[phptrace](https://github.com/Qihoo360/phptrace) maybe a more alternative for you, but it do not support windows now , why not try linux or Mac OS X